# How to use Google Knowledge Graph API

Tags: google-api, freebase, google-knowledge-graph

In what useful way can I use Google Knowledge Graph API at the moment?

Let's say I have the MID for `1990 FIFA World Cup`, which is `/m/014nm_`

and I make this request:

> GET https://kgsearch.googleapis.com/v1/entities:search?ids=%2Fm%2F014nm_&key={MY_API_KEY}

I'll get something like this http://pastebin.com/M1fgj7Ew

Now how can I use that information in a meaningful way?
Just a description and a wikipedia link is not that comprehensive. How can I find out what other entities are linked to this one in the graph?

If I search on Google for `1990 World Cup`, I'll get a Knowledge Graph card like this one [image]

Here I can clearly see useful information like `Best Player` and `Goals scored`, so Google has to have other entities linked to `1990 FIFA World Cup` in the knowledge graph.

Comment: It seems that your dpaste link is broken.

Comment: have you figured this? I could not find how to do it either. it was possible in freebase.

Comment: No, I haven't @jamborta. Plus the freebase API will get shut down on 31st of August and I was hoping for an update on the KG API.

Comment: Unfortunately, I've been unable to find anything actually useful from the knowledge graph api's either.

Answer (score 0):

Google does not expose additional facts from its knowledge graph, so you'd have to get data from an outside source.  To my knowledge there are no complete sources that are available.  There are incomplete ones, such as Wikidata, DBPedia, and loads of the Freebase dump data.

Youtube has a [Freebase Topic API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/searching_by_topic), you can search for videos and channels by Knowledge Graph id.

Comment: As I earlier mentioned, the Freebase Topic API will get shut down on 31st of August, so that's not reliable at the moment.